# Cannot make RestSharp send parameter of object to web api controller (always null)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I have a simple controller method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEntity> GetEntities(ParamsModel args)
{
   //set break point here to examine the args
   return null;
}
```

And here is my `ParamsModel`:

```
public class ParamsModel {
   public string Test;
}
```

And here is my client's method to send get request:

```
//_client here is an instance of RestClient
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntitiesAsync()
{
   var request = new RestRequest("somePath");
   var o = new {                
            Test = "OK"
           };
   request.AddJsonBody(o);       
   return await _client.GetAsync<List<T>>(request);       
}
```

After running the method `GetEntitiesAsync`, the break point (in the controller's method) is hit. However the `args` is null, really?

I've also tried the following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntitiesAsync()
{
   var request = new RestRequest("somePath");
   request.AddParameter("Test", "OK");
   return await _client.GetAsync<List<T>>(request);       
}
```

However that did not work as well (`args` is null in the controller's method).
If I change the controller's method to something like this (and use the client code as right above), I can see the single simple argument of string has value parsed OK ("OK") inside the controller's method:

```
public IEnumerable<IEntity> GetEntities(string Test)
{
   //here we can see that Test has value of "OK"
   return null;
}
```

Really I don't understand what's wrong with my code.
Actually I worked with `RestSharp` at least a year ago but now it seems to have some new methods (such as the `GetAsync` as I used in my code), as before I used the `Execute` and `ExecuteAsync`.

Could you spot anything wrong here? Thanks!

PS: I'm using `RestSharp 106.6.7`

Comment: HTTP GET requests do not allow a body and as such the server wont read it.

Comment: the `AddParameter` will add it as a query string parameter.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, so the `AddParameter` will be added to body? what should I do instead in this case (to help parse data to `ParamsModel` expectedly)? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update action to state explicitly where to look for and bind data using `[FromUri]`

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEntities([FromUri]ParamsModel args) {

    //...

    return Ok(entities);
}
```

> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter.

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri)

The example with `AddParameter`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntitiesAsync() {
   var request = new RestRequest("somePath");
   request.AddParameter("Test", "OK");
   return await _client.GetAsync<List<T>>(request);       
}
```

Should work now.

Note that the model should use properties instead of fields

```
public class ParamsModel {
   public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK, it worked now. Thank you. Do you think that this kind of design (by using `[FromUri]` in this case is just really unnecessary? I mean that in this case the method is obviously `GET`, so its parameters can only be obtained from `URI` (as you said the body will not be read by server). So why do I have to instruct it to read data from `URI` in this case? isn't that so ridiculous ?

Comment: That is just how the framework was designed. I would suggest you review the link in the answer to get a better understanding of model binding.

Comment: yes I know that's by design, but actually it is not like the model binding in MVC (and I'm familiar with MVC before web api). At least in this case the model binding in MVC works in the way making much more sense than Web API.